# Angular style binding

Tags: css, angular

I'm doing an Angular 8 project and I want to bind the dynamic style on HTML. I already learned some from the official document of Angular.
Assuming that in my ts file

```
colorCode: string = "#000000"
```

then I want to bind to HTML

```
<div class="card" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': colorCode}">
 ....
</div>
or
<div class="card" [style.background-color]="colorCode">
 ....
</div>
```

I understand that very well. But the problem is when I want to use a complex style like

```
background-color: rgba($color:#000000, $alpha:0.5)
```

I already tried like this, but it's not working. All I want is dynamic color and the rest are the same.

```
this.colorCode = `rgba($color: ${colorValue}, $alpha: 0.5)`;
```

I'm not sure what I have to do to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

create a function which accept color code and opacity

```
  RGBA(hexCode, opacity) {
    let hex = hexCode.replace("#", "");

    if (hex.length === 3) {
      hex = `${hex[0]}${hex[0]}${hex[1]}${hex[1]}${hex[2]}${hex[2]}`;
    }

    const r = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 2), 16);
    const g = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 4), 16);
    const b = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 6), 16);

    return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},${opacity})`;
  }
```

and use it in template

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'color': RGBA('#fc7303',.7)}">
  Nilesh Patel
</div>
<div [style.background-color]="RGBA('#fc7303',.8)">
    Nilesh Patel-style
</div>
```